# Nuget upgrade issues

Tags: nuget

I recently installed Visual Studio on a new computer and as a result I now have Nuget 1.5.2. This version doesn't seem to work with my old solution. When I add a new project and try adding references via Nuget, it says they are already installed and does nothing, even though that reference doesn't exist in the new project.

Does anyone know why this might be happening or alternatively where I can download the old Nuget (1.4.2)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NuGet Command Line is available as a NuGet package.
Just like with any other NuGet package, you can get a specific version by using the -Version switch in the Package Manager Console.

To get v1.4.2 of the NuGet command line tool, you should execute the following PowerShell script from the Package Manager Console:

*Install-Package Nuget.CommandLine -Version 1.4.20615.182*

Comment: So I guess what I actually meant to ask is where can I download the 1.4.2 version of the Package Manager Console/Visual Studio integration? I believe it would be a .vsix file.

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You could browse the source repository on nuget.codeplex.com and find the revision that is linked to the 1.4.2 release. If you build that revision, you'd get the vsix for that version.